# How do I resize a BitmapImage to 50x50 on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I need to resize a BitmapImage to 50x50 before uploading it to my server. How do I do this on Windows Phone 7 with Silverlight C# .NET on the latest SDK 7.5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(yourBitmapImage);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

wBitmap.SaveJpeg(ms, 50, 50, 0, 100);
```

The stream will contain your resized image

Comment: this is only saving it locally to the phone