# Resizeing image (png) in windowsphone xaml without losing quality

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

In a listbox , i show flag icon for every row . and i use xaml image control in template of listbox item.
after resizing the png files ( flag icons ) , they lose their quality and they are not smooth any more ... what should i do with this problem ? for example in wpf there is a property RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode for managing the quality . but i did not see anything in windows phone ... i was wondering if you guide me how can i fix this issue.
Thanks a lot

```
<Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Height="50" Width="50" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode does not exist in Windows-Phone.

But if you really want to do this code wise without vector images you can do it using Phone 8.1 SDK

Check out BitmapEncoder class. [BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) as part of the Windows.Graphics.Imaging Namespace.

BitmapEncoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for replying , unfortunately i am working on windows phone SDK 8.0

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Bitmap` to deliver the image with the same quality:

```
Image image = new Image();

Uri uri = new Uri(“images/single-pink-rose.png”, UriKind.Relative);

ImageSource img = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(uri);

image.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, img);
```

Refer here for more: [How to Reduce Size of Image in windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163959/)

[How do I resize a BitmapImage to 50x50 on Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641574/)

Hope it helps!